# Regex: Match first two digits of a four digit number

Tags: r, string, datetime

I have:

```
'30Jun2021'
```

I want to skip/remove the first two digits of the four digit number (or any other way of doing this):

```
'30Jun21'
```

I have tried:

```
^.{0,5}
```

https://regex101.com/r/hAJcdE/1

I have the first 5 characters but I have not figured out how to skip/remove the '20'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulating datetimes is better using the dedicated date/time functions.

You can convert the variable to date and use `format` to get the output in any format.

```
x <- '30Jun2021'
format(as.Date(x, '%d%b%Y'), '%d%b%y')
#[1] "30Jun21"
```

You can also use `lubridate::dmy(x)` to convert `x` to date.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need regex for this.  Just use substring operations:

```r
x <- '30Jun2021'
paste0(substr(x, 1, 5), substr(x, 8, 9))

[1] "30Jun21"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sub`

```
 sub('\\d{2}(\\d{2})$', "\\1", x)
[1] "30Jun21"
```

or with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "\\d{2}(?=\\d{2}$)")
[1] "30Jun21"
```

#### data

```
x <- '30Jun2021'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also match the format of the string with 2 capture groups, where you would match the part that you want to omit and capture what you want to keep.

```
\b(\d+[A-Z][a-z]+)\d\d(\d\d)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T4V0OD/1)

```
sub("\\b(\\d+[A-Z][a-z]+)\\d\\d(\\d\\d)\\b", "\\1\\2", "30Jun2021")
```

Output

```
[1] "30Jun21"
```